# laravel shows error when sending email using tls and my own postfix/virtualmin server

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, postfix-mta, virtualmin

We have installed our own postfix/virtualmin server and we have a laravel application,the problem is when we use external smtp servers, it is not problem to use tls option, and the emails are getting sent ok, but when using our new smtp server, when using tls we have this error :

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

It has to be something regarding missing certificates in our postfix/virtualmin server, but, i do not know where to start, we have already a letsencrypt certificates for it, but i believe we maybe need to convert them to ca or something like that ? i'm not sure, that's why i need your help.

Thank you,

Comment: What is the current mail host setting in .env file?

Comment: Hi,
Here iit is : 
```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=exemple.smtp.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=USERNAME-Exemple
MAIL_PASSWORD=fgsfkkfqskdskdqspf
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=mail@exemple.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: Did you try by set the value of MAIL_MAILER to 'mail'

Comment: no, not yet, but will that effect security ?

Comment: Yes that will effect security. But we have to sure that smtp configuration is working. Try something like MAIL_ENCRYPTION="" value.

Comment: yes, removing the tls option and leaving it empty makes the email get sent, but, for security reasons, we do not want to use it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out the problem.

My virtualmin/postfix setup was missing the CA certificiation, and since i used letsencrypt for ssl, i had to put the path of generated CA in the config.

Here : Webmin --> Servers ---> PostFix Mail Server ----> Smtp authentication and encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest [cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) file from [cURL website](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

Edit php.ini (you can do `php --ini` to find it), update (or create if they don't exist already) those two lines:

```
curl.cainfo="/path/to/downloaded/cacert.pem"
...
openssl.cafile="/path/to/downloaded/cacert.pem"
```

Those lines should already exist but commented out, so uncomment them and edit both values with the path to the downloaded `cacert.pem`

Restart PHP and Nginx/Apache.

Comment: this should be done in postfix server or laravel server ? 
But it's weird to do it in laravel server, since we didn't need to do this when using aws ses or sendgrid ... why do i have to do it for our own server.

Comment: First of all laravel is not a server. And other thing is that you are making your own mail server. When you are using laravel then the requests are processed using HTTP protocol but the email protocol is smtp which we have to configure for sending mail from our local or own server

Comment: Once the server is able to sending emails then it can be used with any framework ( not just with Laravel). Amazon ses and sendgrid are pre-configured emails service provider to allow you to use their services to sending emails ( without configure you own) but they have already configure the server thats why they charge after some emails.

Comment: yes, i meant the server where laravel is installed, anyway, this solution didn't work sadly, i still get the same error, maybe this needs to be done in postfix server ?